# Temp data is not getting empty(null) when hitting back(button) through browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am sending a success message in `response` from `API` to `controller` and setting its value in `TempData["Message"]`, now redirecting to some other action method.
like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddFeedbackCategory(IFeedbackCategoryModel modelData)
{
     var message = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(response);
     TempData["Message"] = message.Message;
     return RedirectToAction("CategoryList");
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult CategoryList()
{
     var categoryData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<CategoryModel>>(data);
     return View(categoryData);
}
```

and in the `view` of `CategoryList` I have written code something like this:

```
  @if (TempData["Message"] != null)
    {
        <div id="snackbar" class="snack_success">@TempData["Message"].ToString() 
        </div>
        TempData["Message"] = null;
    }
```

It help to show a success message(retains for 2 second) whenever I add some record in my system like this.

[image]

Now the problem is when I hit back button and then again return to category list this success message appear again. Why its value not becoming null? is there any specific reason or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: When you are redirecting the category list, you are filling TempData[] every time, you need to fill the TempData[] only in the case of successfully inserted. you don't need to fill in every redirection.

Comment: @NiravVasoya Please look at my question again I made some changes might you understand now.

Comment: If you put `[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*", Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]` as an attribute on your `GET` endpoint and then retry, does the problem continue?

Comment: @DivyaAgrawal I have seen your edited question now, good to know you have got the resolution. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you navigate from Page A to Page B. Then you click `Back` on Page B (to go back to Page A). If you do **not** explicitly set caching headers on Page A, the browser *may* decide to display the old version of Page A (that it rendered before going to Page B).

To solve this, one option is to disable browser caching. For example, use this against the `GET` endpoint's action method:

```
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*", Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
```

This will ensure that, if you press the Back button, the browser will be **forced** to hit the server again to re-render Page A (rather than just showing the old version of Page A).

Comment: For .NET Core it's ```[ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]``` - Same behaviour exists there too.